How long can home-made sausages stay in a fridge without risking botulism?
Let say I make make two sausages from scratch. The sausages contains 10% water and 1.5% salt (sodium chloride) with respect to the amout of meat per kg. They do not include nitrate or nitrite.
I boil one sausage for 10 minutes and then I put both sausages in a fridge with 3.8C/33F.
These sex conditions should now hold for both sausages.

Absence of oxygen
Low Acid
Low Salt
High moisture
Low sugar
Temperature (higher than 4.4C/44F [1])

Is there any risk the uncooked, or both sausages can cause botulism after a week in the fridge? Do I need to re-boil the already cooked sausage to make it safe to eat?
The purpose of this question is to get an answer regarding risk of botulism with raw sausages in a fridge. This seems very close to leaving garlic in oil for too long in the fridge, which is unsafe. However, one of the samples are cooked and one is not. Will the risk regarding boutalism be different?
Refs:

[1]https://www.fda.gov/files/food/published/Fish-and-Fishery-Products-Hazards-and-Controls-Guidance-Chapter-13-Download.pdf
What is the lowest temperature at which botulism spores are killed?


Isn't this just the usual uncooked/partially cooked meat situation? I would assume that the inside of a sausage is not anaerobic but perhaps I'm wrong.

If you are worried about safety, botulism is unlikely, what would be much more likely are E. Coli, salmonella, Clostridium perfringens and Staphylococcus aureus.

I know people are confused here and always try to supply many details in the hope of finding exceptions to food safety rules. It doesn't work that way! Unless you made your sausages from a recipe that is designed and tested to be in the next-more-shelf-stable-category, they are just like any other cooked food.

I want this question to focus on butalism, because IMO, it seems all conditions are true. @dbmag9, (Homemade) Salami has a risk of having boutalism because there is no air inside them. Do you mean that sausage not dried can' have that?

@Bojack that's not how food safety works, please see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. Your line of thinking contains several of the misconceptions listed there. In short, you get a binary "safe/not safe" judgement, and hear if the food needs to be kept refrigerated or not. For a few unusual cases, it might be common knowledge why the food falls into the unexpected category (garlic-in-oil because of botulism) but in general, food safety rules are simplified, straightforward, and don't answer "why".
